# Individual User Account in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

Can any one please explain this change in "**Change Authentication**" dialog box. Previously it was easy creating a project with Individual user accounts, but now this is annoying, because I am forced to fill in the options. I couldn't find any help regarding it either, so StackOverflow is my last option. Please refer the image below to understand what I mean. If you find it too silly and unwilling to answer, then please point me to any resource that will help me understand this.

[image: Change Authentication dialog box Three new fields]

Comment: The "Learn more" link is an article that will help you understand this. The other option in the dropdown is "Store user accounts in-app". Perhaps that is what you are looking for?

Comment: @GorgiRankovski , Yes what you said is true regarding the other option, but its only available for MVC application not WebAPI. For WebAPI the option shown in the image is the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this setting is used to configure Cloud authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C in ASP.NET Core.

> Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) is a cloud identity management solution for web and mobile apps. The service provides authentication for apps hosted in the cloud and on-premises.

If you want to configure the Cloud authentication with Azure Active Directory B2C in ASP.NET Core, you should firstly create  the Azrue AD B2C and then register the app in Azure AD B2C.

The app inside the Azure AD B2C will contains Application ID  and its domain name, then you could use that Application ID, domain name and set Sign_in or Sign_up policy to `B2C_1_SiUpIn`.

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c?view=aspnetcore-1.1). Notice: This article is for VS2019 but almost same.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I saw the screen in docs for the first time because of you. However I need some help to create individual User accounts authentication for WebAPI not web application. But thanks I will try to dig more info.